# not getting value after empty() function

Tags: php

I'm sending a parameter with post. This parameter holds a ZERO value.

When i'm trying to use the empty method it should return 1 if the parameter is not empty and 0 if the parameter is zero.

If i'm using this code:

```
var_dump(empty($_REQUEST['gender_preferences']) );
```

i'm getting the result: 1.

If i'm using this code:

```
var_dump(!empty($_REQUEST['gender_preferences']) );
```

i'm not getting the 0 value;

Why does this happen and how can i fix it?

Comment: 1) what is a ZERO value 2) "should return 1 if the parameter is not empty" - huh? doesn't that contradict its name LOL 3) it's unclear what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
""  /* (an empty string) */
0  /* (0 as an integer)*/
"0"  /* (0 as a string)*/
NULL
FALSE
array() /*  (an empty array)*/
var $var;  /* (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)*/
```

Try using `isset` instead

```
isset($_REQUEST['gender_preferences'])
```

Comment: how can you suggest `isset` without knowing what he wants to do? that's quite irresponible.

Comment: Read the question clearly, he describes what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

empty function Determine whether a variable is empty or not and your requested variable contains value i.e zero 0.

to check variable contains zero

```
if($_REQUEST['gender_preferences']){
  //value is not zero
}else{
  //value is zero
}
```

Comment: just.... don't. check the last column: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php